# how to add boundary to an image in webpage

Tags: image, boundary

```
<html>
<h3> MY FIRST WEBPAGE </h3>
<H1> DESIGNING MY FIRST WEBPAGE </H1>
<title> MY FIRST TAB </title>
<img src="3333.jpg"
     width="800" 
     height="500" >
<style>
    body {font:12px Verdana,Arial; color #428bca; background-color:#5bc0de}
    
    
</style>
                 


</html>
```

how to add boundary to image . ineed to knwo like how toadd a red coloured boundary to enclose the image in  a table format

Answer (score 0):

Add Borders to a Images using HTML & CSS

Using HTML/CSS to add borders to an image is easier than what you think. Before you add an image to your post in the text module,  you need to switch to the text editor. Then, you will add the image and see the HTML code of the picture. This will look like the following images.

￼

After adding the image to the text module, type this style=”border:5px solid #000000; padding:3px; margin:5px” to add the borders to your images. It will look like the next picture.

￼

As result of that code, the image will look similar to the next picture.

￼

Feel free to make any change to the border width, color, padding, and margin to your images. Also, you can change to the visual editor after you are done with the picture to see the changes that you’ve made. Let us know below if you have any comments or questions; we’d love to hear from you.

Comment: please free free for more details

Comment: Your images all just look like ￼. Can you fix that?